# Magento - Filtering Configurable products on simple product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, layered-navigation, stock, out-of-stock

I have an issue in Magento 1.9.

We have a list of configurable products. Like ex. Shoes
We filter the products by attribute: Manufacturer [NIKE]
Then try to filter by the attribute: SIZE [43]

However the result is a collection of ALL the configurable products that have the attribute SIZE attached to it, so at this point, the result is not:
- All Nike shoes with size 43 in stock.
- But, instead, it gives us all NIKE shoes that have a simple product, which has the Attribute Size [43]. Regardless of its stock status.

I hope you can help me sort this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was so simple, but overlooked anyway... The attribute applied to both configurable and simple. By restricting it only to the simple we got the required result.

To elaborate.
The configurable product can have an attribute called size.
A simple can have one assigned ex. XS and an inventory value like 1

Filtering the products on a configurable's attribute would result in showing all results.

Go edit the attribute and change where the size applies. Should only apply to a simple.